# How can I pass xml in payload via retrofit

Tags: android, xml, retrofit

I'm using retrofit 1.9 and SimpleXMLConverter. I try to send request to server with payload as XML.

```
@POST("/M/Bean?wsdl")
        Observable<MainNode> getObject(@Body MyObject object);
```

I have this xml as string

```
 String payload = "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV> MY_OBJECTS</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";

retrofit.getObject(payload)
```

and in logs from retrofit I see

> D/Retrofit: `<string>&lt;SOAP-ENV:Envelope
>   MY_OBJECTS SOAP-ENV:Envelope&gt;</string>`

How can I pass full XML payload without `<string>`?